# limit plot title to only show a certain number of decimal places

Tags: python

For a plot that I am making, I have:

```
 plt.suptitle('Name:{0}, MJD:{1}, std dev > {2}'.format(pname, mjd[i], rmslevel), fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
```

I want the number that will appear in the place of {2} (aka rmslevel) to only show 2 decimal places.

I have seen similar questions to this of course, and the solutions:

```
print "%.1f" % number
```

But I can't figure out how to get this to work in the context of the .format things that I have going on in the same line.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this.

```
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(123.678956)   # Or "{:.2f}".format(123.678956)
'123.68'
```

Your code now turns to

```
plt.suptitle('Name:{0}, MJD:{1}, std dev > {2:.2f}'.format(pname, mjd[i], rmslevel), fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
```

You may find [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) useful.

[Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatexamples) contain some examples.

> In most of the cases the syntax is similar to the old %-formatting,
>   with the addition of the {} and with : used instead of %. For example,
>   '%03.2f' can be translated to '{:03.2f}'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this -

```
plt.suptitle('Name:{0}, MJD:{1}, std dev > {2}'.format(
             pname, mjd[i], ("%.2f" % rmslevel)
             ), fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
>>> print "{0:.2f}".format(4)
4.00
```

So in your example:

```
plt.suptitle('Name:{0}, MJD:{1}, std dev > {2:.2f}'.format(pname, mjd[i], rmslevel), fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
#                                          ^^^^^^^ Notice the change.
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 1):

```
'Name:{0}, MJD:{1}, std dev > {2:.2f}'.format(pname, mjd[i], rmslevel)
```